# Parallel compilation on multiple hosts with a makefile

Tags: makefile

I am currently paralleling my compiling jobs using `make -jN`.

I have a set up with multiple computers all using the same file system. Is it possible to spread the compilation out onto multiple hosts?

Answer (score 0):

GNU make itself doesn't support this.  You can integrate it with something like [distcc](https://code.google.com/p/distcc/) to get support for distributed compilation.